# How to use <p:spinner with attribut max=current year

Tags: jsf

I want to use `<p:spinner`  where attribut `max` equals current year in jsf but without using backend bean.

I use jsf 2.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use #{now} from OmniFaces http://showcase.omnifaces.org/managedbeans/now

Example:

```html
#{of:formatDate(now, 'yyyy')}
```

Comment: `#{now}` *is* a bean

Comment: I know, but <p:spinner /> is a JSF Tag. You can not just use javascript to set the year.